# Angular Momentum

Tags: physics

Here is my question

> A particle attached to a string of length $2$ m is given an initial velocity of $6 \text {m/s}$. The string is attached to a peg and, as the particle rotates about the peg, the string winds around the peg. What length of string has wound around the peg when the velocity of the particle is $20 \text {m/s}$?

I'm training for physics olympiads. That's why I need help.

Comment: This is a physics question.

Comment: What have you tried? What are your own thoughts on the problem? Were should we even start helping you when we do not know where you have problems?

Comment: I dont know the correct equation.

Comment: @Bobtrollsten : Do you have the diagram ? i think it will be helpful.

Comment: @Sou No, currently I don't have it.

Comment: If we can find the correct equation to use, It'd be solved easily.

Comment: Guys the context is right there in the question: the OP is training for the physics olympiad and this is a practice question...

Comment: @user7530 Absoulety, It's and Might I post my questions which involves mathematical calcuations here (like this question)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good question. The intuitive approach is to apply conservation of momentum, which would give you a length of $3/5$ meters. But **why** is angular momentum conserved in this system? After all, linear momentum is not conserved, and there is no obvious rotational symmetry to the system.

There may be a clever way of arguing that angular momentum must be conserved, but it's also straightforward to derive this fact. We can parameterized the system by a one-dimensional configuration space representing the angle $\theta$ by which the string has wound around the peg. As the string winds, it shortens: let $l(\theta)$ be the (monotonic decreasing, with $l(0) = 2$, but otherwise unknown) length of the string after it has wound by $\theta$.

Assuming the particle has mass $m$, the kinetic energy of the particle is $$T = \frac{1}{2}m [2\pi l(\theta) \dot \theta]^2;$$
since there is no potential energy the Euler-Lagrange equations are
$$\frac{d}{dt} \left(4\pi^2 ml(\theta)^2\dot\theta\right) - 4\pi^2 m l(\theta)\dot\theta^2 l'(\theta)=0$$
or
\begin{align*}
8\pi^2 m l(\theta)l'(\theta)\dot\theta^2 + 4\pi^2ml(\theta)^2\ddot\theta - 4\pi^2 ml(\theta)\dot\theta^2l'(\theta)&=0\\
l'(\theta)\dot\theta^2 + l(\theta)\ddot\theta &=0\\
\frac{d}{dt}\left(l(\theta)\dot\theta\right)&=0,
\end{align*}
and we see that $3/5$ meters is indeed the correct approach.

Comment: What a great answer this was! Thanks a lot.

Comment: @user7530 : I think the torsion must exist due to the tension force ? I just simply can't imagine why its not have torsion. In physics version of the solution probably it is ignored because the radius of the peg is small.